# random amount of textviews on a single cardview not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I am pulling Room data from a web page. Room title and people in that room. The number of people changes and I need to display all people in a particular room on a single cardview.

I've tried a lot of not so great ideas. such as creating 16 separate text views manually. 16 is the max number of people that can be in a room. however when the arraylist has no value I get null fatal error.

This is from main_activity.

```
if (!dd.isEmpty()){
    Log.d("anoter check", String.valueOf(dd));
    if (dd.size() != 15){
        int intlvl = dd.size();
        int newlvl = 15 - intlvl +1;
        for (int i =0;i<newlvl;i++) {
            dd.add(" ");
        }
    }
```

This is from my RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

    List<String> dd = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mActionRooms.get(0).split(",")));
    Log.d("anoter check", String.valueOf(dd));
    if (dd.size() != 15){
        int intlvl = dd.size();
        int newlvl = 15 - intlvl +1;
        for (int i =0;i<newlvl;i++) {
            dd.add(" ");
        }
    }
    holder.action_Rooms.setText(dd.get(0));
    holder.action_Rooms1.setText(dd.get(1));
    holder.action_Rooms2.setText(dd.get(2));
    holder.action_Rooms3.setText(dd.get(3));
    holder.action_Rooms4.setText(dd.get(4));
    holder.action_Rooms5.setText(dd.get(5));
    holder.action_Rooms6.setText(dd.get(6));
    holder.action_Rooms7.setText(dd.get(7));
    holder.action_Rooms8.setText(dd.get(8));
    holder.action_Rooms9.setText(dd.get(9));
    holder.action_Rooms10.setText(dd.get(10));
    holder.action_Rooms11.setText(dd.get(11));
    holder.action_Rooms12.setText(dd.get(12));
    holder.action_Rooms13.setText(dd.get(13));
    holder.action_Rooms14.setText(dd.get(14));
    holder.action_Rooms15.setText(dd.get(15));
    holder.action_Players1.setText(mRooms.get(position));}

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    action_Rooms15 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms);
    action_Rooms14 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms1);
    action_Rooms13 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms2);
    action_Rooms12 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms3);
    action_Rooms11 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms4);
    action_Rooms10 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms5);
    action_Rooms9 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms6);
    action_Rooms8 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms7);
    action_Rooms7 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms8);
    action_Rooms6 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms9);
    action_Rooms5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms10);
    action_Rooms4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms11);
    action_Rooms3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms12);
    action_Rooms2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms13);
    action_Rooms1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms14);
    action_Rooms = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Rooms15);
    action_Players1 =itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_Players1);
    parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a single TextView in an item of RecyclerView

Use a List to provide the count for creating text views, in the adapter

Every time a new person joins the room, add new data in list and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");
        
        for(int i = 0;i<mActionRooms.size();i++){
            List<String> dd = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mActionRooms.get(i).split(",")));
            holder.action_Rooms.setText(mActionRooms.get(position));
        }

Comment: I'm still not getting how to do this. How can I help you help me?